# Fastest Log4j2 configuration for multiple java process / multiple machine production environment

Tags: log4j2

We have 4 java processes running on machine01, 1 java process on machine02, 2 java processes on machine03.  We would like them to all write logging to the same file on machine01.  What is the best config to accomplish this?  We need production grade very fast high throughput logging.

Right now we have a 5th process on machine01, ecplogger, that runs the UdpSocketServer and uses RollingRandomAccessFile Appender wrapped with Failover Appender.  All other processes on machine01, machine02 and machine03 write to a Socket Appender wrapped with an Async appender wrapped with a Failover Appender.

It works sort of, however I get these errors in the main java process on machine01 and I get lots of logging to the Failover appender:

```
2016-02-05 18:23:06,123 AsyncAppender-local_process_async ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:ecplogger:6000 for appender local_process_socket
2016-02-05 18:34:50,746 AsyncAppender-local_process_async ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:ecplogger:6000 for appender local_process_socket
2016-02-05 18:47:25,233 Log4j2-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@18b4aac2]1 ERROR Appender local_process_async is unable to write primary appenders. queue is full
2016-02-05 18:47:25,234 Log4j2-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@18b4aac2]1 ERROR Appender local_process_async is unable to write primary appenders. queue is full
2016-02-05 18:47:25,235 Log4j2-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@18b4aac2]1 ERROR Appender local_process_async is unable to write primary appenders. queue is full
2016-02-05 18:47:25,236 Log4j2-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@18b4aac2]1 ERROR Appender local_process_async is unable to write primary appenders. queue is full
2016-02-06 01:56:44,647 AsyncAppender-local_process_async ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:ecplogger:6000 for appender local_process_socket
2016-02-06 06:02:13,308 AsyncAppender-local_process_async ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:ecplogger:6000 for appender local_process_socket
2016-02-07 06:40:36,386 AsyncAppender-local_process_async ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:ecplogger:6000 for appender local_process_socket
```

---

Configuration:
Every java process is started with:

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector \
-DAsyncLogger.ExceptionHandler=com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.EcpExceptionHandler \
```

The ecplogger java process that runs UdpSocketServer uses the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Used by ecplogger -->
<Configuration name="log4j2.server.xml" status="debug" monitorInterval="60">
<Appenders>
<!-- Don't forget to set system property
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
-DAsyncLogger.ExceptionHandler=com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.EcpExceptionHandler
-->
<!--Asynchronous loggers and appenders will automatically flush at the end of a batch of events, even if immediateFlush is set to false -->
<!-- The default buffer size is 262144 bytes, double it-->
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="/opt/twc/logs/ecp.log" filePattern="/opt/twc/logs/ecp.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" append="true" bufferSize="524288" ignoreExceptions="false">
<PatternLayout>
<Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
</Policies>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>

<Console name="STDERR" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n"></PatternLayout>
</Console>

<Failover name="Failover" primary="RollingRandomAccessFile">
<Failovers>
<AppenderRef ref="STDERR"/>
</Failovers>
</Failover>

</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Root level="all">
<AppenderRef ref="Failover"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

All other java processes use the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Used by every process -->
<Configuration status="debug" name="log4j2.xml" monitorInterval="60">
<Appenders>
<Socket name="local_process_socket" host="ecplogger" port="6000" protocol="UDP" immediateFail="false" immediateFlush="true" reconnectionDelayMillis="1000" connectTimeoutMillis="10000" ignoreExceptions="false">
<SerializedLayout/>
</Socket>

<!-- Don't forget to set system properties in ecp.conf
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
-DAsyncLogger.ExceptionHandler=com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.EcpExceptionHandler
-->
<Async name="local_process_async" blocking="false" shutdownTimeout="5000" bufferSize="32768" errorRef="STDERR" ignoreExceptions="false" includeLocation="false">
<AppenderRef ref="local_process_socket"/>
</Async>

<Console name="STDERR" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n"></PatternLayout>
</Console>

<Failover name="Failover" primary="local_process_async">
<Failovers>
<AppenderRef ref="STDERR"/>
</Failovers>
</Failover>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
<Logger name="com.google" level="error"/>
<Logger name="org.mybatis" level="error"/>
<Logger name="org.apache.ibatis" level="error"/>
<Logger name="com.ryantenney" level="error"/>
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="error"/>
<Logger name="org.apache.activemq" level="error"/>
<Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="error"/>
<Logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="error"/>

<Logger name="org.springframework" level="info"/>
<Logger name="com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.history.HouseholdHistorySummaryQueue" level="warn"/>
<Logger name="com.twc.ctg.ecp.persistence.mappers.HouseholdHistorySummaryMapper" level="warn"/>


<Root level="info">
<AppenderRef ref="Failover"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

---

Log4j2 output on debug

Ecplogger, the UdpSocketServer:

```
2016-02-05 18:17:36,228 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.server.xml]
2016-02-05 18:17:36,274 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2016-02-05 18:17:39,738 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_65, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2016-02-05 18:17:39,903 main DEBUG Groovy Scripting Engine Version: 2.0, Language: Groovy, Threading: MULTITHREADED, Compile: true, Names: {groovy, Groovy}
2016-02-05 18:17:39,903 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 97 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:39,907 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:39,958 main DEBUG Starting 1 Log4j2Scheduled threads
2016-02-05 18:17:39,980 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:39,983 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,089 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:40,332 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(log4j2.server.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:40,347 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:40,486 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,585 main DEBUG createPolicy(interval="null", modulate="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:40,585 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,587 main DEBUG createPolicy(={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false)})
2016-02-05 18:17:40,587 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,628 main DEBUG createAppender(fileName="/opt/twc/logs/ecp.log", filePattern="/opt/twc/logs/ecp.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}", append="true", name="RollingRandomAccessFile", immediateFlush="null", bufferSize="524288", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false)])), Strategy=null, PatternLayout(%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n), Filter=null, ignoreExceptions="false", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(log4j2.server.xml))
2016-02-05 18:17:40,672 main DEBUG Starting RollingRandomAccessFileManager /opt/twc/logs/ecp.log
2016-02-05 18:17:40,673 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:40,727 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,729 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(log4j2.server.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:40,730 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,754 main INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2016-02-05 18:17:40,755 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:40,760 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-2
2016-02-05 18:17:40,830 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(PatternLayout(%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n), Filter=null, target="SYSTEM_ERR", name="STDERR", follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:40,830 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_ERR.false
2016-02-05 18:17:40,831 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,831 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="STDERR", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:40,873 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=failovers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FailoversPlugin].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,876 main DEBUG createFailovers(={STDERR})
2016-02-05 18:17:40,876 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FailoverAppender].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,899 main ERROR appender Failover has no parameter that matches element Failovers
2016-02-05 18:17:40,899 main DEBUG createAppender(name="Failover", primary="RollingRandomAccessFile", ={[STDERR]}, retryIntervalSeconds="null", Configuration(log4j2.server.xml), Filter=null, ignoreExceptions="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:40,900 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,930 main DEBUG createAppenders(={RollingRandomAccessFile, STDERR, Failover primary=null, failover={STDERR}})
2016-02-05 18:17:40,941 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,942 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Failover", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:40,942 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,943 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ALL", includeLocation="null", ={Failover}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.server.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:40,970 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,971 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root})
2016-02-05 18:17:40,972 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.server.xml] initialized
2016-02-05 18:17:40,972 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.server.xml]
2016-02-05 18:17:41,030 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.server.xml] OK.
2016-02-05 18:17:41,031 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-1
2016-02-05 18:17:41,031 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3339ad8e OK
2016-02-05 18:17:41,570 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3
2017-02-05 18:17:41,585 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer
2016-02-05 18:17:41,587 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3,component=StatusLogger
2016-02-05 18:17:41,618 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3,component=ContextSelector
2016-02-05 18:17:41,639 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3,component=Loggers,name=
2016-02-05 18:17:41,641 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3,component=Appenders,name=STDERR
2016-02-05 18:17:41,662 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3,component=Appenders,name=Failover
2016-02-05 18:17:41,662 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@17f052a3,component=Appenders,name=RollingRandomAccessFile
2016-02-05 18:17:41,683 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=AsyncContext@17f052a3] at URI /opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.server.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@6bf0219d) with optional ClassLoader: null
2016-02-05 18:17:41,692 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2016-02-05 18:17:41,693 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=AsyncContext@17f052a3, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@6bf0219d] started OK.
2016-02-05 18:17:41,727 main DEBUG AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=CACHED
2016-02-06 00:00:00,416 Log4j2-0 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[/opt/twc/logs/ecp.log to /opt/twc/logs/ecp.log.2016-02-05, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-02-07 00:00:00,663 Log4j2-0 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[/opt/twc/logs/ecp.log to /opt/twc/logs/ecp.log.2016-02-06, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-02-08 00:00:00,802 Log4j2-0 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[/opt/twc/logs/ecp.log to /opt/twc/logs/ecp.log.2016-02-07, renameEmptyFiles=false]
~
```

One of the other processes:

```
2016-02-05 18:17:37,098 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.xml]
2016-02-05 18:17:37,159 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2016-02-05 18:17:37,356 main DEBUG Groovy Scripting Engine Version: 2.0, Language: Groovy, Threading: MULTITHREADED, Compile: true, Names: {groovy, Groovy}
2016-02-05 18:17:40,741 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_65, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2016-02-05 18:17:40,742 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 97 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:40,743 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:40,813 main DEBUG Starting 1 Log4j2Scheduled threads
2016-02-05 18:17:40,814 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:40,847 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.SerializedLayout].
2016-02-05 18:17:40,864 main DEBUG createLayout()
2016-02-05 18:17:40,865 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,080 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:41,178 main DEBUG createAppender(host="ecplogger", port="6000", protocol="UDP", SSL=null, connectTimeoutMillis="10000", reconnectionDelayMillis="1000", immediateFail="false", name="local_process_socket", immediateFlush="true", ignoreExceptions="false", SerializedLayout(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.SerializedLayout@4e3958e7), Filter=null, advertise="false", Configuration(log4j2.xml))
2016-02-05 18:17:41,233 main DEBUG Starting DatagramSocketManager UDP:ecplogger:6000
2016-02-05 18:17:41,234 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,253 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="local_process_socket", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,253 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,295 main DEBUG createAppender(={local_process_socket}, errorRef="STDERR", blocking="false", shutdownTimeout="5000", bufferSize="32768", name="local_process_async", includeLocation="false", Filter=null, Configuration(log4j2.xml), ignoreExceptions="false")
2016-02-05 18:17:41,296 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,336 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:41,366 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:41,509 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,512 main INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2016-02-05 18:17:41,529 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2016-02-05 18:17:41,530 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-2
2016-02-05 18:17:41,573 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(PatternLayout(%d{ISO8601} %-14mdc{application} %-5level [%t] %logger - %msg%n), Filter=null, target="SYSTEM_ERR", name="STDERR", follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:41,574 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_ERR.false
2016-02-05 18:17:41,576 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,602 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="STDERR", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,603 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=failovers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FailoversPlugin].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,603 main DEBUG createFailovers(={STDERR})
2016-02-05 18:17:41,604 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FailoverAppender].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,606 main ERROR appender Failover has no parameter that matches element Failovers
2016-02-05 18:17:41,609 main DEBUG createAppender(name="Failover", primary="local_process_async", ={[STDERR]}, retryIntervalSeconds="null", Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null, ignoreExceptions="null")
2016-02-05 18:17:41,610 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,611 main DEBUG createAppenders(={local_process_socket, local_process_async, STDERR, Failover primary=null, failover={STDERR}})
2016-02-05 18:17:41,619 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,627 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="com.google", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,660 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,670 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="org.mybatis", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,671 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,672 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="org.apache.ibatis", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,672 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,688 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="com.ryantenney", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,688 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,689 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="org.apache.http", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,702 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,703 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="org.apache.activemq", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,703 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,704 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="org.eclipse.jetty", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,704 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,717 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", name="org.apache.cxf", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,720 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,721 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="INFO", name="org.springframework", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,721 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,722 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="WARN", name="com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.history.HouseholdHistorySummaryQueue", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,734 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,735 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="WARN", name="com.twc.ctg.ecp.persistence.mappers.HouseholdHistorySummaryMapper", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,735 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,735 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Failover", level="null", Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,736 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,737 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={Failover}, ={}, Configuration(log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2016-02-05 18:17:41,746 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2016-02-05 18:17:41,747 main DEBUG createLoggers(={com.google, org.mybatis, org.apache.ibatis, com.ryantenney, org.apache.http, org.apache.activemq, org.eclipse.jetty, org.apache.cxf, org.springframework, com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.history.HouseholdHistorySummaryQueue, com.twc.ctg.ecp.persistence.mappers.HouseholdHistorySummaryMapper, root})
2016-02-05 18:17:41,750 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.xml] initialized
2016-02-05 18:17:41,756 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.xml]
2016-02-05 18:17:41,764 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.xml] OK.
2016-02-05 18:17:41,764 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-1
2016-02-05 18:17:41,765 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@1324409e OK
2016-02-05 18:17:41,771 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2
2016-02-05 18:17:41,774 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer
2016-02-05 18:17:41,780 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
2016-02-05 18:17:41,783 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
2016-02-05 18:17:41,790 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.ibatis
2016-02-05 18:17:41,791 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=
2016-02-05 18:17:41,792 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.google
2016-02-05 18:17:41,792 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.activemq
2016-02-05 18:17:41,792 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.eclipse.jetty
2016-02-05 18:17:41,793 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.twc.ctg.ecp.persistence.mappers.HouseholdHistorySummaryMapper
2016-02-05 18:17:41,794 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.cxf
2016-02-05 18:17:41,794 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.http
2016-02-05 18:17:41,794 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.http
2016-02-05 18:17:41,795 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.history.HouseholdHistorySummaryQueue
2016-02-05 18:17:41,800 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.springframework
2016-02-05 18:17:41,800 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=com.ryantenney
2016-02-05 18:17:41,802 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.mybatis
2016-02-05 18:17:41,809 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=local_process_socket
2016-02-05 18:17:41,811 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=STDERR
2016-02-05 18:17:41,811 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=Failover
2016-02-05 18:17:41,813 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=AsyncContext@18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=local_process_async
2016-02-05 18:17:41,818 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=AsyncContext@18b4aac2] at URI /opt/twc/ecp/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@2cd2a21f) with optional ClassLoader: null
2016-02-05 18:17:41,824 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2016-02-05 18:17:41,825 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=AsyncContext@18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext@2cd2a21f] started OK.
2016-02-05 18:17:41,841 main DEBUG AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=CACHED
```

~

Comment: well, if i look at the [appender reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) , you could probably do that 'single' output with either a JDBC or a syslog appender.

Comment: Really what I am getting at is with the current setup, the throughput is not fast enough